# Lookup YouTube Metadata using C#

Tags: c#, youtube

I have a list of YouTube video keys. For example, "2GnN3xLa0Js" from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GnN3xLa0Js.

How can I use C# to lookup the basic metadata such as the video's length and author?

Comment: You can request the data from YouTube using the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect to youtube api to retrieve all required data. You could scrape the url and get the data but its a hard way. I am sure if you will google it you will find many good tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

This might be out of date but it's something I've been using recently and that is libvideo library by Bar Arnon. Now this might not be ideal as it's really used for downloading the video rather than just sniffing the metadata. Sadly there isn't a specific, "getData" method.

https://github.com/i3arnon/libvideo

Once added to your project, you can do this...

```
using VideoLibrary;

:
:

public class ytMetadata {
 public string uri;
 public string title;
 public string fullName;
 public VideoFormat format;
 public int resolution;
 public ytMetadata (string u, string t, string n, VideoFormat f, int r) {
  uri = u; title = t; fullName = n, format = f, resolution = r;
 }
}

public ytMetadata getYTMetadata(string uri) {
 YouTube yt = YouTube.Default;
 YouTubeVideo ytv = yt.GetVideo(uri);
 return new ytMetadata(ytv.Uri, ytv.Title, ytv.FullName, ytv.Format, ytv.Resolution);
}
```

The code is a sort of cut down version of what I am using, so it might not suit what you are doing. The library has both synchronous and asynchronous methods.

Comment: Ok, so the problem here is I used an example of what I was using for one problem when in reality it's not the best solution at all.

Essentially you can just pull the details of the video using YouTube's own methods.. 

http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=<id>

For example...

http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=dQw4w9WgXcQ